# Calling actions from instance of third party component in my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

I have the following code where inside my React component I'm using a third party component -- `FineUploader` in my case.

Upon uploading files, it calls its `onComplete` function. From here, I'm trying to call my action creators to handle post-upload processes but I'm unable to access my `props` or `actions` from there because this is all outside of my component.

Up to that point, everything is working. I'm able to call `uploader` instance from my component and upload the file to my Azure Blob Storage and get the `fileName` and `blobName` once the upload is completed.

It's funny that I'm stuck at the easier part!

Here's my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import FineUploaderAzure from 'fine-uploader-wrappers/azure'

// Components
import Gallery from './gallery/index';

// Actions
import * as myActions from '../myActions';

// Instantiate FineUploader
const uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
    options: {
        cors: {
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: false
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 'http://localhost:123/getsas'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container'
        },
        callbacks: {

            onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {

                const fileName = uploader.methods.getName(id);
                const blobName = uploader.methods.getBlobName(id);

                // I now need to call my action creator to handle backend stuff
                // Or I can call the handleFileUpload function inside my component.
                // How do I access either my action creator or handleFileUpload function from here?

            }
        }
    }
})

class FileUploader extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.handleFileUpload = this.handleFileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    handleFileUpload(fileName, blobName) {

        debugger;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Gallery uploader={uploader} />
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {

    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(myActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileUploader)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following approach that works. I'm not sure if this is the best way or there's a more elegant approach. I won't accept my answer as the correct one and let everyone post their comments and votes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import FineUploaderAzure from 'fine-uploader-wrappers/azure'

// Components
import Gallery from './gallery/index';

// Actions
import * as myActions from '../myActions';

// Instantiate FineUploader
const uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
    options: {
        cors: {
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: false
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 'http://localhost:123/getsas'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container'
        }
    }
})

class FileUploader extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.handleFileUpload = this.handleFileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

       uploader.on('complete', (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) => {

            const originalName = uploader.methods.getName(id);
            const blobName = uploader.methods.getBlobName(id);

            this.handleFileUpload(originalName, blobName);
       }
    }

    handleFileUpload(fileName, blobName) {

        // Received fileName and blobName. We can call our actions creators here.
        this.props.actions.someAction(fileName, blobName);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Gallery uploader={uploader} />
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {

    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(myActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileUploader)
```

Comment: This helped me with a similar issue I was having, thank you!